# select top 1 from a group by and order by in a query

Tags: sql-server

I have a table with data like:

```
ID    Field_name   change_date  prev_value  current_value

1      USER_NAME    01/01/2013     test         test11
1      USER_NAME    04/02/2013     test11       test12
2      USER_GENDER  06/01/2013     M             F
2     USER_GENDER   02/01/2013     F             M
```

When i group by field_name and order by change_date i will get something like

```
ID    Field_name   change_date  prev_value  current_value
2      USER_GENDER  06/01/2013     M             F
2     USER_GENDER   02/01/2013     F             M 
1      USER_NAME    04/02/2013     test11       test12
1      USER_NAME    01/01/2013     test         test11
```

Now i need to select top 1 row for each field_name. Please suggest

Thanks

EDIT:

```
select @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(Field_name) 
                            from 
                            (
                                select Field_name,change_date,prev_value,current_value
                                from
                                (select *,
                                 row_number() over (partition by Field_name order by change_date desc) as 
                                ranker from tbl_User
                                )Z
                                where ranker = 1 and ID = '1' 
                            )
                    FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
                    ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
                ,1,1,'')
```

Expected output:

```
ID     USER_GENDER  USER_NAME 
2         M            
1                     test11
```

Comment: Is your ID column a mistake, or do you really have more than one row sharing the an ID?

Comment: By definition you have already `GROUP`ed `BY` the `field_name` so each row returned should be unique with regard to `field_name`. If you loop through the results you will have the top one for each `field_name`.

Comment: No i am getting all the rows but grouped by and ordered by

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Windowing functions should be able to do the trick with any recent version of SQL Server

```
select ID, Field_name,  change_date,  prev_value,  current_value
from
(select *,
 row_number() over (partition by Field_name order by change_date desc) as 
ranker from table
)Z
where ranker = 1
```

Comment: Hi 1_CR, I have edited my question...I am not able to run that query..my concern is i don't know how many field_names i will have in the table. SO i need to display as expected table using pivot with prev_value as its value

Comment: @user1882705, post a separate question specific to your pivoting requirement. There are several pivoting experts on this forum, unfortunately I am not one of them.